# Deleting a row from a table and passing a Boolean flag to API, without deleting the actual object

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing a spa with AngularJS and consuming an api with mvvm in C #.

I can delete a line after clicking the delete button, but on the server I want only to change a boolean flag to true by keeping the data in Sql Server.

I've tried other ways, and I was even deleting the object through Postman, but I do not want to delete but only change a Boolean property to the record that no longer exists in my view table.

I'll leave my code so it can be better understood.

Any help is welcome.

I have tried to pass the id and the object in api controller, similar to http.put, because I want to change a Boolean property, so I wanted to keep the id, name, last name, email and isdelete that after the click, changes to delete the line in the view becomes true in the database.

```
 <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="register in registers">
                    <td style="display:none">{{register.UserId}}</td>
                    <td>{{register.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{register.LastName}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="register.IsActive" disabled /></td>
                    <td>{{register.Email}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a ng-click="editRegister($event, register)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="" ng-click="deleteRegister()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

My controller.js:

```
 $scope.deleteRegister = function (register) {
    var index = -1;
    var listOfRegister = eval($scope.registers);
    for (var i = 0; i < listOfRegister.length; i++) {
        if (listOfRegister[i].register === register) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (index === -1) {
        alert("Something gone wrong");
    }
    $scope.registers.splice(index, 1);
    $http({
        method: 'Delete',
        url: 'http://localhost:51734/api/UserAPI/',

    }).then(function (res) {
        alert('Exc');
        $scope.GetAllRegisters();
    })
};
```

And My controller.api:

```
[HttpPut]
    [Route("api/UserAPI")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(UserViewModel uservm)
    {
        try
        {                                
            var registerDeleted = ctx.User.Find(uservm.UserId);
            uservm.IsDelete = false;
            uservm.IsActive = true;
            if (registerDeleted != null)
            {
                uservm.IsActive = false;
                uservm.IsDelete = true;
                registerDeleted.Name = uservm.Name;
                registerDeleted.LastName = uservm.LastName;
                registerDeleted.IsActive = uservm.IsActive;
                registerDeleted.Email = uservm.Email;
                registerDeleted.IsDelete = uservm.IsDelete;
                ctx.Entry(registerDeleted).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "User not found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a table and when you click on the delete icon you want the row to be deleted, is that correct? also is the db / api side working? and this is just a UI issue of updating the current template.

Comment: Okay, when I click on the delete icon I can delete the line, the way you told me, it reduces the code making it cleaner and easier. Now I want to change the property of the object to true. Drop the view record but keep it in the db / with status isDelete to true.With the same id, name, lastName, isActive = false, Email, and isDelete = true.I do not want to permanently delete the object data from db /. I want to keep the record but with the property working with a flag from isDelete to true when removing the object from the view.

Comment: ive updated the answer for you, but as Andrei Dragotoniu mentioned you could just pass in the the userId and not the entire UserViewModel, this again would make your code neater and less to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are talking about is soft deleting rows of data.
in the database add a new boolean field called Status or IsDeleted or whatever you fancy, with a default value of *false*.
When you hit the Delete button on the UI, issue a request to simply update that flag from *false* to *true*

When you request the list of things to show on the UI, oly return those where the flag is set to *false*.

This is basically the whole idea behind soft deleting data. You only mark the data is deleted, you don't actually delete it.

If you want, later on you can add a process where you move the soft deleted data to an archived table, just to keep things tidy. Doing things this way has the added benefit that you can always *undelete* the data, should you need to. All you need really is to change the flag back to *false* and you're done, everything works and the data gets displayed.

One final point from me, if you all you want to do is soft delete an item, then all you need is to pass the id of the record. you don't need to worry about changes to other fields. You wouldn't normally update information AND delete it at the same time. So create a simple controller which responds to PUT, for example:

```
[HttpPut]
    [Route("api/UserAPI")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int userId)
    {                                       
         var foundUser = ctx.User.Find(userId);
         foundUser.IsDeleted = true;
         ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

of course, add all your validation, return codes, everything you need, but this is essentially all you need.

Don't forget to change the method which returns the active users, to ignore those where the IsDeleted flag is true.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, but I can not get my controller.js in the $ scope.deleteRegister method to call the PUT in my controller.api.

I changed the code as you told me, it gives the following error: ReferenceError: userId is not defined
    at ChildScope. $ scope.deleteRegister (registerController.js: 38).

I'll leave my code as a new question, so that you can help me, if possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the API is the issue you are setting `uservm.IsDelete = false;` then setting `registerDeleted.IsDelete = uservm.IsDelete;` therefore it would always be **false** in the database.

If the template is the issue i would recommend getting the `index` from the `data-ng-repeat`, this would reduce the amount of code you have written and make it easier to see what is going on.

This will remove the row from the table:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="(index, register) in registers">    
     <td>
       <a href="data-ng-click="deleteRegister()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
    </td>
</tr>      

$scope.deleteRegister = function (index) {
   $scope.registers.splice(index, 1);
}
```

**Update from comment:**

You need to retrieve the object then make the change, and save it.

```
var registerDeleted = ctx.User.Find(uservm.UserId);
if (registerDeleted != null)
{
    registerDeleted.IsDelete = true;
    registerDeleted.IsActive = false
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it deletes the object from my view.cshtml, but I want to make a promisse in the $scope.deleteRegister method that called my controller.api for the object to continue with the same data values ​​in bd / but with a flag set to true, after clicking on the icon to delete the record.

Comment: Surely the code that populates the registers in the first place is checking that the flag isDelete = false? can you update your question with $scope.GetAllRegisters() code please

Answer (score 0):

Now I already know how to delete a record from my View.index, which is with splice in my controller.js

```
$scope.deleteRegister = function (index) {

    $scope.registers.splice(index, 1);
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'http://localhost:51734/api/UserAPI/',
    }).then(function (res) {
        alert('Exc');
        $scope.GetAllRegisters();
    })

};
```

But I can not get it to communicate with my method in my controller.api, I want to change only the flag isDelete = true, after clicking the delete button on my UI.

My controller.api

```
//DELETE: api/UserAPI/5
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/UserAPI")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int userId)
    {
        try
        {
            var foundUser = ctx.User.Find(userId);

            if (foundUser != null)
            {
                foundUser.IsDelete = true;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
}
```

And my view.index

```
      <tr ng-repeat="(index, register) in registers">
        <td>
          <a href="" ng-click="deleteRegister()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
         </td>
      </tr>
```